# itertools.groupby in a django template

Tags: python, django, group-by, django-templates, python-itertools

I'm having an odd problem using `itertools.groupby` to group the elements of a queryset. I have a model `Resource`:

```
from django.db import models 

TYPE_CHOICES = ( 
    ('event', 'Event Room'),
    ('meet', 'Meeting Room'),
    # etc 
)   

class Resource(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
    # other stuff
```

I have a couple of resources in my sqlite database:

```
>>> from myapp.models import Resource
>>> r = Resource.objects.all()
>>> len(r)
3
>>> r[0].type
u'event'
>>> r[1].type
u'meet'
>>> r[2].type
u'meet'
```

So if I group by type, I naturally get two tuples:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> g = groupby(r, lambda resource: resource.type)
>>> for type, resources in g:
...   print type
...   for resource in resources:
...     print '\t%s' % resource
event
    resourcex
meet
    resourcey
    resourcez
```

Now I have the same logic in my view:

```
class DayView(DayArchiveView):
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(DayView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        types = dict(TYPE_CHOICES)
        context['resource_list'] = groupby(Resource.objects.all(), lambda r: types[r.type])
        return context
```

But when I iterate over this in my template, some resources are missing:

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="resources">
{% for type, resources in resource_list %}
    <option disabled="disabled">{{ type }}</option>
    {% for resource in resources %}
        <option value="{{ resource.id }}">{{ resource.name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

This renders as:

[image: select multiple]

I'm thinking somehow the subiterators are being iterated over already, but I'm not sure how this could happen.

(Using python 2.7.1, Django 1.3).

(EDIT: If anyone reads this, I'd recommend using the built-in [`regroup` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#regroup) instead of using `groupby`.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think that you're right. I don't understand why, but it looks to me like your `groupby` iterator is being pre-iterated. It's easier to explain with code:

```
>>> even_odd_key = lambda x: x % 2
>>> evens_odds = sorted(range(10), key=even_odd_key)
>>> evens_odds_grouped = itertools.groupby(evens_odds, key=even_odd_key)
>>> [(k, list(g)) for k, g in evens_odds_grouped]
[(0, [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]), (1, [1, 3, 5, 7, 9])]
```

So far, so good. But what happens when we try to store the contents of the iterator in a list?

```
>>> evens_odds_grouped = itertools.groupby(evens_odds, key=even_odd_key)
>>> groups = [(k, g) for k, g in evens_odds_grouped]
>>> groups
[(0, <itertools._grouper object at 0x1004d7110>), (1, <itertools._grouper object at 0x1004ccbd0>)]
```

Surely we've just cached the results, and the iterators are still good. Right? Wrong.

```
>>> [(k, list(g)) for k, g in groups]
[(0, []), (1, [9])]
```

In the process of acquiring the keys, the groups are also iterated over. So we've really just cached the keys and thrown the groups away, save the very last item.

I don't know how django handles iterators, but based on this, my hunch is that it caches them as lists internally. You could at least partially confirm this intuition by doing the above, but with more resources. If the only resource displayed is the last one, then you are almost certainly having the above problem somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for investigating; I tried it with ~10 resources and had at most one resource per group -- I fixed it by populating the context with `(t, list(r)) for t, r in groupby(...)`

Comment: Yes, the iterator is being pre-iterated, Django converts the iterator into a list without iterating through the grouped items. I've added an explanation in a separate answer.

Comment: this is not an answer to the question.

Comment: @dopatraman what do you think the question is? I think the question is "are the subiterators being pre-iterated somehow?" I take it you disagree?

Comment: Yes. I think the question is "why did this unexpected thing happen?" Your answer is a suspicion as to why it happened, not an explanation.

Comment: @dopatraman It's not even a suspicion why. It's just a confirmation that the OPs guess was probably right. (Which *is* an answer to the question I think was asked. But we can agree to disagree about that.)

Answer (score 27):

Django's templates want to know the length of things that are looped over using `{% for %}`, but generators don't have a length.

So Django decides to convert it to a list before iterating, so that it has access to a list.

This breaks generators created using `itertools.groupby`. If you don't iterate through each group, you lose the contents. Here is [an example from Django core developer Alex Gaynor](https://twitter.com/alex_gaynor/statuses/156118678235123712), first the normal groupby:

```
>>> groups = itertools.groupby(range(10), lambda x: x < 5)
>>> print [list(items) for g, items in groups]
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

Here is what Django does; it converts the generator to a list:

```
>>> groups = itertools.groupby(range(10), lambda x: x < 5)
>>> groups = list(groups)
>>> print [list(items) for g, items in groups]
[[], [9]]
```

There are two ways around this: convert to a list before Django does or prevent Django from doing it.

## Converting into a list yourself

As shown above:

```
[(grouper, list(values)) for grouper, values in my_groupby_generator]
```

But of course, you no longer have the advantages of using a generator, if this is an issue for you.

## Preventing Django from converting into a list

The other way around this is to wrap it in an object that provides a `__len__` method (if you know what the length will be):

```
class MyGroupedItems(object):
    def __iter__(self):
        return itertools.groupby(range(10), lambda x: x < 5)

    def __len__(self):
        return 2
```

Django will be able to get the length using `len()` and will not need to convert your generator into a list. It's unfortunate that Django does this. I was lucky that I could use this workaround, as I was already using such an object and knew what the length would always be.

Comment: Nice, glad someone with Django knowledge weighed in.